# drop .php extension for folders - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently I drop the .php extension in the URL.

I use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that if I have a folder it doesn't work. I have to add it to every folder group. I know there is an easier way.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the regex so that you aren't *excluding* requests that have a `/` in it.

Change your first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.php
```